# Error with cmake_minimum_required line

Tags: linux, cmake

I am very new to cmake, and have not found an issue like this anywhere so I assume it's just a stupid mistake.

Here is my **CMakeLists.txt** file:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
project (Methane)

set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -pthread -g -O0")

add_executable (Output methane.cpp)

include_directories (../osdk-core/api/inc)
include_directories (../osdk-core/utility/inc)
include_directories (../osdk-core/hal/inc)
include_directories (../osdk-core/api/inc)
include_directories (../sample/platform/linux/inc)
include_directories (../osdk-core/protocol/inc)
include_directories (../osdk-core/platform/linux/inc)
```

When I cmake the project, there are no errors. But when I make the project (in the build folder) it gives me this **error**:

```
error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ 
token
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
                       ^
```

If I missed any info here, or I need to give more context just let me know.

Thanks all.

Comment: What command are you using?

Comment: Please provide some information about your directory structure and the commands you are executing including the current directory you are executing them from.

Comment: I am using **cmake ..** from my build directory then using **make** in the build directory. The **make** command is what gives me the error

Comment: The project directory is called Methane, the osdk-core(has all my header and src files) directory is on the same plane as Methane. the build folder is in Methane. I executed cmake from build directory by command: **"cmake .."**. That always succeeds and writes the build files to the build directory. Then I make the project while in the build directory by using command: **"make"**. That is what pulls the error mentioned in post.

Comment: Is methane.cpp an only file you are compiling? It looks like the compiler tries to compile CMakeLists.txt for some reason. Is it possible that you somehow included CMakeLists.txt in methane.cpp by mistake, or maybe pasted "cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)" string into it?

Comment: OMG yes, I did do that for some reason since other things werent working and forgot to remove it. Thank you so much for the fix! I guess it was really just a stupid mistake haha. :)